# What's the special notation?

Tags: mathematical-economics, stock-market, financial-markets

I'm studying "[ALGORITHMIC AND HIGH-FREQUENCY TRADING](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107091144)". Page 249 of it tries to find a formula for $h(t,q)$. First, it supposes $h(t,q) = \bar\kappa log  \space\omega(q,t)$ then let $\omega(t)=[\omega(t,\bar{q}),\omega(t,\bar{q}-1),...,\omega(t,q)]'$.

My question is: "What is the meaning of notation $'$, in $\omega(t)=[\omega(t,\bar{q}),\omega(t,\bar{q}-1),...,\omega(t,q)]'$? 
Is it Lagrange's notation for differentiation?

Following, I added a photo of this page. I marked the notation which I mean.
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the transpose, in this case of the vector.